# Spring-Loaded setup for Intellij

Tags: spring, hotswap, spring-loaded

I downloaded spring-loaded.jar and tried to set it up for IntelliJ but unfortunately it did not work.

So, here is my questions:

1) What needs to be done exactly to set it up?
2) How do I trigger hot-swap?

Comment: What is spring-load? You mean [spring-loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded)?

Comment: Yes. I edited my question to correct that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [spring-loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) project.

As stated in the official documentation, you have to add this java agent argument in your IntelliJ "run configuration" (the configuration that runs your application - it may be a Java class or a servlet container like Tomcat):

```
-javaagent:<pathTo>/springloaded-{VERSION}.jar
```

Once this agent is loaded, it watches `*.class` files on disk and reloads them if modified (by your IDE, for example).

**Warning:** depending on your application, and especially if it contains caches, data intialized at startup... you may have to write specific plugins or event listeners to reinitialize those.

Comment: I get the following error when I run the application within Intellij:
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ~/Downloads/springloaded-1.1.4.jar

Comment: I was able to make this work with --no-verify flag on a Windows machine. For some reason I am still running into the same issue on Mac OSX.

Comment: On mac use -noverify